# How to getAttribute from java servlet to javascript?

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-3.0

I send request with attribute `intCate` to client by java servlet :

```
package controller.admin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import dao.impl.ListNewCategoryImplDAO;
import model.ListNewCategory;
import model.New;
import model.NewCategory;
import service.ListNewCategoryService;
import service.NewCategoryService;
import service.NewService;
import service.impl.ListNewCategoryServiceImpl;
import service.impl.NewCategoryServiceImpl;
import service.impl.NewServiceImpl;

@WebServlet("/admin/new/edit")
@MultipartConfig
public class AdminUpdateNewController extends HttpServlet{
    NewService service = new NewServiceImpl();
    NewCategoryService serviceCate = new NewCategoryServiceImpl();
    ListNewCategoryService serviceListCate = new ListNewCategoryServiceImpl();
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            req.setAttribute("listCate", serviceCate.getAll());

            int id = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));
            New item = service.get(id);
            req.setAttribute("item", item);
            
            List<ListNewCategory> list = serviceListCate.getCategorys(id);
            
            String[] strCate = new String[list.size()];
            int[] intCate = new int[list.size()];
            
            for(int i=0;i<intCate.length;i++) {
                strCate[i] = serviceCate.get(list.get(i).getNewCategoryId()).getName();
                intCate[i] = list.get(i).getNewCategoryId();
            }
                        
            req.setAttribute("category", serviceCate.getAll());
            req.setAttribute("intCate", intCate); 
            req.setAttribute("strCate", strCate);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/view/admin/edit-new.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resp.sendRedirect("/admin/new/list");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
}
```

But I can't use `intCate` variable by javascript:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!-- Start header section -->
  <jsp:include page = "./header/header.jsp" flush = "true" />
  <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix = "c" %>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title">Sửa tin tức</div>
                <hr>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/new/edit">
               
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-1">Tiêu đề</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-1" placeholder="Tiêu đề" name="title" value="${item.title}">
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-2">Mô tả</label>
                    <textarea id="input-2" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" name="description">${item.description}</textarea>                 
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-3">Hình ảnh</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="input-3" placeholder="Hình ảnh" name="new_image" value="${item.newImage}">
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-7">Chi tiết</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control ckeditor" id="input-7" rows="4" cols="50" name="detail">${item.detail}</textarea>                 
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-16">Lượt xem</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input-16" placeholder="Lượt xem" name="view_count" value="${item.viewCount}">
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-12">Ngày tạo</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="input-12" placeholder="Ngày thêm vào" name="created_date" value="${item.createdDate}">
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-13">Người tạo</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-13" placeholder="Được tạo bởi" name="created_by" value="${item.createdBy}">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="input-15">Chọn danh mục</label>
                        <select class="form-control valid chosen-select" data-placeholder="Chọn danh mục"  multiple id="input-6" name="category" required aria-invalid="false">
                            <c:forEach items="${category}" var="item">
                                <option value="${item.newCategoryId}">${item.name}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                  </div>


               <div class="form-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/product/list">Hủy</a></button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Thêm</button>
                </div>                
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay toggle-menu"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
<jsp:include page = "./footer/footer.jsp" flush = "true" />
<script>
        var date = new Date();
        
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        
        if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
        if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
        
        var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
        
        
        document.getElementById('the-date').value = today;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(".editor");
    CKFinder.setupCKEditor(editor, "/view/admin/assets/plugins/ckfinder/");
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
          no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var intCate = <%=request.getAttribute("intCate")%>;
    console.log(intCate);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi put `<%=request.getAttribute("intCate")%>` inside `''` i.e : `'<%=request.getAttribute("intCate")%>'` and try again . Also , check if your browser console showing any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<% int boardSize = (Integer) request.getAttribute("boardsize"); %>` in the `<body>` tag and then use `<script>var boardsize =<%= boardSize%>;` in javascript

Note: Mình cũng là người Việt